# Running Java Program from Command Line Linux

Tags: java, linux, command-line

I am not very experience with java and this is driving me crazy. I wrote a java program `FileManagement` and I need to run it from the command line.

I can compile it from the command line with `javac FileManagement/*.java` which will create all the classes in that folder but when I try `java FileManagement.Main` it says :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   FileManagement/Main

The thing is that I have tried this same procedure in a remote computer and it is working fine. It is not working on mine.

Comment: http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html has a good intro for beginners.

Comment: @Pramod. That link is for windows though...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your `Main` class is in a package called `FileManagement`, then try:

```
java -cp . FileManagement.Main
```

in the parent folder of the `FileManagement` folder.

If your `Main` class is not in a package (the default package) then *cd* to the `FileManagement` folder and try:

```
java -cp . Main
```

More info about the CLASSPATH and how the JRE find classes:

- [How Classes are Found](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html)
- [Setting the class path (Solaris/Linux)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)

Comment: @Altober, good to hear that. I encourage you to read a bit about the classpath so you know why it didn't work.

Comment: @AnsersonGreen, just provide the parameters after Main.

Answer (score 7):

Guys let's understand the syntax of it.

1. If class file is present in the Current Dir.

   **java -cp . fileName**
2. If class file is present within the Dir. Go to the Parent Dir and enter below cmd.

   **java -cp . dir1.dir2.dir3.fileName**
3. If there is a dependency on external jars then,

   **java -cp .:./jarName1:./jarName2 fileName**

   Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

(This is the KISS answer.)

Let's say you have several .java files in the current directory:

```
$ ls -1 *.java
javaFileName1.java
javaFileName2.java
```

Let's say each of them have a `main()` method (so they are programs, not libs), then to compile them do:

```
javac *.java -d .
```

This will generate as many subfolders as "packages" the .java files are associated to. In my case all java files where inside under the same package name `packageName`, so only one folder was generated with that name, so to execute each of them:

```
java -cp . packageName.javaFileName1
java -cp . packageName.javaFileName2
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the package name of your class? If there is no package name, then most likely the solution is:

```
java -cp FileManagement Main
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Bart K gave the same solution and It worked. Thanks again Thomas

Comment: If the main class was named "Main" (without package), and if the class was simply in the directory named "FileManagement". The same as cd FileManagement ; java cp . Main

Comment: Ah, sorry, you added `FileManagement` to the classpath. I thought you tried to execute `FileManagement` and gave `Main` as a command line parameter.