# Setting the java classpath: -cp vs -classpath in JDK versions 1.0 through 1.8?

Tags: java, classpath

I've been looking at compiling and running Java programs from the command line and I keep seeing different versions of setting the classpath: [-cp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692229/running-java-program-from-command-line-linux) vs [-classpath](http://shivasoft.in/blog/java/compile-and-run-java-program-in-package-from-command-line/). I want to think these are identical but can someone more knowledgeable than me confirm or refute this?

Comment: I voted this up, simply because there *is* a difference between `-Djava.class.path` and the quite synonymous `-classpath/-cp` family of options. When using `-Djava.class.path`, you can't use wildcards to specify the location of a folder of JAR files.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can easily find answer by checking official documentation. From [Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#BEHJBHCD) or [Unix](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/classpath.html#BEHJBHCD) versions:

> The `java` command has a `-cp` option that is an **abbreviation** for `-classpath`.

Comment: similarly, for the unix version, see corresponding path (replace windows with unix in above path). The main diff between windows and unix is that windows allows wildcards in the CLASSPATH definition, but unix does not. So in unix, if you want to specify a wildcard, you need to do something like : java -cp ".:dir/*"

Answer (score 4):

They are the same.  Do `java -help` to see all the options. `-cp and -classpath` do the same thing.